# I want to get the name of the user who has logged in

Tags: php, jquery

I have a piece of php code which will display the current username who has logged in, i want to add this php code to jquery code so that the username can get auto filled. I dont know jquery code to make it possible as i am new to jquery.

This is my php code where i can get username:

```
<?php   
$this->data['page_title'] = 'User Profile';
$user_id = $this->input->get('username');
if( !isset($user_id) )
{
    $user_id = $_SESSION['username'];
    echo $user_id;
} 
?>
```

I don't know how to add this code to .js code.

Comment: Auto-filled a text input? You could just echo it `<input type="text" value="<? echo $user_id ?>">`

Comment: Thnkq :) it works.. @c.k

Comment: Please accept it as your answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using it to auto-filled a text input. PHP alone can do this, You can echo it like this.

```
<input type="text" value="<? echo $user_id ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign php value to jquery var in js like this

```
var name = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>";
console.log(name);
```